# Turkish characters to contact form

Tags: php

How to add the Turkish characters to this form:

in the `$mailed = mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($message).'?=', $message, $headers);`
I already added `'=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode` which only fixed the subject. but all the body still appear something like this: ÄžÃœLÅžÃ–Ã‡I ÄŸÃ¼ÅŸiÃ¶Ã§Ä± if typed ĞÜLŞÖÇI ğüşiöçı for example.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['subject'])) {

$companyname = $_POST['company-name'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "";
$subject = "$subject";
$message = "Name: $name\nPhone Number: $areacode $phone\nCity: $city\nState: $state\n\n$message";
$headers = "From: $email";

$mailed = mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($message).'?=', $message, $headers);

if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
$response = ($mailed) ? "1" : "0";
} else {
$response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" : "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";
}

echo $response;
} else {
echo "Form data error!";
}
```

Comment: Which encoding does your input data (=`$_POST['message']`) have?

Comment: Try adding a Content-Type header: `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` (for HTML) or `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8` (for plain text).

Comment: I just tried adding this "$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=?utf-8?B?' . "\r\n";" it did not work. is that what you had in mind mate?

Comment: Why do you have `?utf-8?B?` in there? Try this: `$headerFields = ["From: $email", "MIME-Version: 1.0", "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"]; $headers = implode("\r\n", $headerFields);`

Comment: Do I add that on the top of the code?

Comment: The form stopped working

Comment: Add it before `$mailed = mail(...` and see whether it works.

Comment: no mate, it make the form to stop working. Ah what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also encode your message (UTF8).
You can do it using the `headers` parameter of the `mail` function.

**additional_headers**

> String to be inserted at the end of the email header. This is
>   typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). Multiple
>   extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). Validate
>   parameter not to be injected unwanted headers by attackers.

Replace the next code:

```
$headers = "From: $email";
```

With:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email . "\r\n";
```

Should work.
Update me if not.

Comment: However, I have added "/n" in here "$message = "Name: $name\nPhone Number: $areacode $phone\nCity: $city\nState: $state\n\n$message";" but it seems like they are all being ignored. why is that? So when I get the email in my inbox, everything is on one line...

Comment: Try using `\r\n` instead.

Comment: Same problem I am afraid.

Comment: Basically, when using the `MIME-version` header, you can use `HTML` in your email. So try to use `<br />` instead of the `\n`.

Comment: @Leo You should also use `htmlspecialchars()` for escaping possibly inserted HTML from $_POST['message']. Otherwise, it would be really simple to distribute malicious HTML and JavaScript by using your form.

Comment: Don't understand this bit mate what do you mean? Thank you.